# Unable to set property 'Property name' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs, webapi

Browser IE11
AngularJS
Api returning data and is being loaded to custom objects like

```
apiData.map(function(item){
 return {
    id: item.Id,
    name: item.Name,
    types:{}
});
```

This 'types' property is being populated as following by init method:

```
for (int i=0, i<data.length; i++){
data[i].types = getTypes(); -- this line gives undefined error
}
```

Can you please tell what is wrong here?
getTypes()  function is returning correct data.

Thanks in advance for providing suggestions.
Sonali Das

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I see that you have some syntax errors here:

```
apiData.map(function(item){
 return {
    id: item.Id,
    name: item.Name,
    types:{}
 } //missing a curly braces here
});
```

syntax again:

```
for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++){ //not int, ";" not ","
  data[i].types = getTypes();
}
```

Second, .map will not change the original array but return a new array, make sure that you have assigned the new returned array to `data`

It should look like this

```
var data = apiData.map(function(item){
 return {
    id: item.Id,
    name: item.Name,
    types:{}
  }
});
for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++){ 
   data[i].types = getTypes(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
for (int i=0, i<data.length; i++){
  var datatype = getTypes(data[i].types);
}
```